# jQuery autocomplete: characters missing in user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am debugging a jQuery autocomple instance (v1.1) on a "city" input field.

The autocomplete data binding is set on the `keyup` event of the field, only if the field value length is at least 2 and only if the value has changed.

The data binding, the hints list and the autocomplete are working fine.
But something is wrong. In the log I see that many times the 3rd and some times even the 4th character is missing in the city input value posted to the server. Some examples:

```
"trpani" instead of "trapani"
"fienze" instead of "firenze"
"scndicci" instead of "scandicci"
"brdisi" instead of "brindisi"
"paermo" instead of "palermo"
"caliari" instead of "cagliari"
```

I do not succeed in replicate the bug, but I am sure it cannot be by chance! The error occurs just at the 3rd character. It seems that during the insert, Javascript processing *collides* with the keyboard buffer.

So, I guess but I am not sure, people type `f i r e n z e`, but eventually the `r` character is missed, and the final value of the input is `fienze` that is eventually posted to the server.

**Question**

What is happening? Why I do not succeed in replicate the error? What is wrong?

Here is the code used to set the autocomplete:

```
/*
 * here I store the previous value
 */
var storeCity;
$('#City').keydown(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    storeCity = (val.length >=2 ? val.substring(0,2):"");
});

/*
 * the autocomplete is set only if
 * - the City value has changed compared to the storeCity value
 * - the City value has lenght at least 2
 * - remark: using the keypress does not solve the issue
 */
$('#City').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length>=2 && val.substring(0,2)!=storeCity){
        getLocations('#City');
    }
});

function getLocations(cityId){
    var hint = $(cityId).val().substring(0,2);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/include/getLocations.asp",
        data: ({location : hint}),
        async: false,
        error: function() {},
        success: function(dataget) {
            var result = dataget.split("\n");

            $(cityId).flushCache();
            $(cityId).autocomplete(result, {
                pleft: 100px,
                minChars: 2,
                matchContains: true,
                max: 3000,
                delay: 100,
                formatItem: function(row){...},
                formatMatch: function(row){ return row[0]; },
                formatResult: function(row){ return row[0]; }
            });

            $(cityId).result(function(event,data){...});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is a problem in your logic implementation as storeCity will always be equal to empty string on your first call to getLocations(). Because you set it on keydown callback function. Try using keypress instead which is always call before keyup.

Comment: No, I have tested but the issue is not solved.

Comment: You're not using the autocomplete widget correctly. You should be applying it once to the `input`.

Comment: How can the value sent to the server be the whole word ("trapani", etc.) if you are actually getting a `substring(0, 2)` of the text entered?

Comment: @juan. 2 lenght strings are sent to the server, where a query runs with a like clause. The issue regards the user input. As I said, the databinding and the autocomplete work right.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: the autocomplete is working right. Anyway, what is wrong if I change the source several times depending on the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I resolved with some heuristics. I thought that the problem is due to events conflict. So I tryed to get better performance.

- initialize the autocomplete *once*, outside the getLocation() method
- store the $('#city') object in a variable
- put the $city.result method outside the getLocation() method

Here is the result code:

```
var $city = $('#City');
var storeCity;

$city.keypress(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    storeCity = (val.length >=2 ? val.substring(0,2):"");
});

/*
 * the autocomplete is set only if
 * - the City value has changed compared to the storeCity value
 * - the City value has lenght at least 2
 * - remark: using the keypress does not solve the issue
 */
$city.keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length>=2 && val.substring(0,2)!=storeCity){
        getLocations('#' + $city[0].id);
    }
});

$city.autocomplete({
    pleft: 100px,
    minChars: 2,
    matchContains: true,
    max: 3000,
    delay: 50
});

$city.result(function(event,data){...});

function getLocations(cityId){
    var hint = $(cityId).val().substring(0,2);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/include/getLocations.asp",
        data: ({location : hint}),
        async: false,
        error: function() {...},
        success: function(dataget) {
            var result = dataget.split("\n");

            $(cityId).flushCache();
            $(cityId).autocomplete(result, {
                formatItem: function(row){...},
                formatMatch: function(row){ return row[0]; },
                formatResult: function(row){ return row[0]; }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the order of initialization should reverse. The initialization of the autocomplete component should happen only once, when the page is loaded. See example attached:

```
  $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
           // Put your ajax request here
        }
  });
```

Comment: No, the whole city list is too big to be loaded once at the page load. So I flush and reload the local data everytime $(cityId).val().substring(0,2) changes.